Transitioning from engineering to math research
I'm a PhD student researching fluid mechanics in an aerospace engineering lab. My undergrad background was primarily mathematics.
I originally decided to join this lab, which was the same lab I was in during undergrad, because my advisor had enough funding to fully fund the entirety of my PhD, and the pay was confortable. My university also has a really strong graduate math program, so I thought that I'd be able to continue to learn about mathematics during my graduate studies on the side. My advisor also convinced me to stay by saying that I would get to work on projects relating to my interests in math. So overall I thought this lab would be a great fit for me. I would get more specific about my current research and my research interests in math, but I want to avoid doing so in case it makes it obvious who I am (I think some of my colleagues are on here).
However, I now feel like engineering isn't aligned with my research interests. My research projects are mostly for industry sponsors who don't care much for math. Additionally my advisor seems to have backtracked and is asking me to be in their words "less of a mathematician". I'm in an awkward position because I would like to continue fluid mechanics research in a mathematics lab but I don't think I can leave my current lab without burning bridges to a lot of people in the field. My current plan is to take as many graduate math courses during my PhD with the goal of transitioning to applied math research after my PhD.
How easy would this transition be?
